# A little bug about collision in my program

Tags: c++, collision

I'm trying to figure out my problem for an hour. 
I'm going to draw what is happening.

```
char trap = 'Q'; 
char character = 'L';

.... 
.Q..
..L.
....
```

**when L moves up and Q moves to right they collide and the program ends. but:**

```
....
.QL.
....
....
```

**when L moves to left and Q moves to right they dont collide the same way as the example above instead, whats happening is:**

```
....
..Q.
....
....
```

here's my code. sorry for my bad english :(

**test if the move is 'w' , 'a' , 's' or 'd' :**

```
void cave::move(int& x, int& y, char m, char unit)
{
                if ( m == 'W' || m == 'w' ) // if moves up
                {
                    floor[x][y] = tile;
                    x -= 1;
                    for ( unsigned short int x = 0; x < 3; x++ )
                    {
                            if ( floor[x][y] == wall && floor[x][y] == trap[x] )
                            {
                                x += 1;
                                trapsMove();
                        }
                        }
                        floor[x][y] = unit;
                }

                else if ( m == 'A' || m == 'a' ) // if moves to left
                {
                            floor[x][y] = tile;
                            y -= 1;
                        for ( unsigned short int x = 0; x < 3; x++ )
                        {
                            if ( floor[x][y] == wall && floor[x][y] == trap [x] )        
                            {
                                   y += 1;
                                   trapsMove();
                                }
                        }
                            floor[x][y] = unit;
                }

                else if ( m == 'S' || m == 's' ) // if moves down
                {
                        floor[x][y] = tile;
                            x += 1;
                            for ( unsigned short int x = 0; x < 3; x++ )
                        {
                                if ( floor[x][y] == wall && floor[x][y] == trap[x] )
                                {
                                    x -= 1;
                                    trapsMove();
                                }
                            }
                            floor[x][y] = unit;
                }
               else if ( m == 'D' || m == 'd' )  // if moves to right
               {
                        floor[x][y] = tile;
                            y += 1;
                            for ( unsigned short int x = 0; x < 3; x++ )
                            {
                                if ( floor[x][y] == wall && floor[x][y] == trapx] )
                                {
                                    y -= 1;
                                    trapsMove();
                                }
                            }
                            floor[x][y] = unit;
               }
               else 
                        control(); 
               return;
 }
```

**ai moves function**

```
void cave::trapsMove() 
{
                    int r[3]; // each index will hold the movement of traps 
                    for ( unsigned short int x = 0; x < 3; x++ )
                    {
                            r[x] = rand() % 4 + 1;
                            if ( r[x] == 1 ) // moves up
                                move(traps_positionX[x],traps_positionY[x],'w',trap[x]);
                            else if ( r[x] == 2 ) // moves to left
                                move(traps_positionX[x],traps_positionY[x],'a',trap[x]);
                            else if ( r[x] == 3 ) // moves down
                                move(traps_positionX[x],traps_positionY[x],'s',trap[x]);
                            else if ( r[x] == 4 ) // moves to right
                                move(traps_positionX[x],traps_positionY[x],'d',trap[x]);
                    }
                    return;
}
```

**check if collide**

```
bool cave::collision()
{
                    for ( unsigned short int x = 0; x < 3; x++ )
                    {
                            if ( floor[character_positionX][character_positionY] == trap[x] )
                                return true;
                    }
                    return false;
}
```

Comment: Good description of the problem, but that's quite a lot of code for people to read. Probably most of it is irrelevant. Could you try making an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @BoBTFish sorry i thought they would just run the code.

Comment: Busy busy busy!  A small amount of code is going to get more help!

Comment: @KarolyHorvath thanks for reacting like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems from your code that the Trap and Player switch their position.
However the position switch from your Trap (Q) overwrites the Player (L) with a floor tile.

Essentially this happens:

(1) .QL.

(2) .L.. // L and Q inhabit the same tile

(3) ..Q. // Q overwrites L with a '.' tile

---

Your code suffers from convolution, because you try to either do too much in one function or do it in several different places. This leads to you missing for instance the necessary collision check in the above example.

A better strategy would be to try to structure your program flow. For instance you currently have:

(1) Prompt for a direction

(2) Move player tile

(2a) If player hits a tile which is a Trap or a Wall (typo in your code, must be || instead of &&) move the traps

<-- (2a) is another pitfall where traps can do two moves in a row.

(3) Move the traps

(4) check for collision

(5) repeat from (1)

I think what you wanted was:

(1) Prompt for a direction

(2) Move player tile

(2a) check for collision

(3) Move traps

(3a) check for collision

(6) repeat from (1)

---

As for the refactoring try to recycle your code. For instance in your move() function the char 'w' (...) only influences the 'x' or 'y' variable. Thus you could write it also as

```
move(...) {
    if((m=='w')||(m=='W')) { y = y+1 }
    else if((m=='a')||(m=='A')) { x = x-1 } // same for SD

    if(floor[x][y] != wall) {
        // set new position to object, if it can't move, just don't set it
    }
}
```

This way you don't have to copy&paste your for-loop with minimal alterations.

Comment: oh. it does makes sense to me.
since in the game loop. the user move will execute first, then trap. 
so if i execute the trapmove first, the L will overwrite the Q

Comment: what do you mean by  "is another pitfall where traps can do two moves in a row."?
they can only do two moves if their move is restricted like bumping the walls or colliding to co-traps.

Comment: you are right, im doing too much in one function, so when the player bump the wall, the traps will do move again, instead of prompting again the user for a direction.

Comment: i use loop to check all the co-traps if they collide each other.

Comment: Your move() may call trapsMove() which calls move() -- this continues until one successful move for traps is done (if their first move attempt would be obstructed by walls or other traps of course). After which you call trapsMove another time from your main()-method, therefore traps will move up to two times per "game round", esp. if traps are located along walls.

Comment: when i run the game, the traps are working just fine.
if move() calls trapsMove() because the move is prohibited, then the following code will not be executed.
therefore, floor[x][y] = unit; ,which will move the unit , will not be executed. so in which part they are moving more than one time per game round?